# If checkbox is unchecked, undo the data-price attribute using jquery

Tags: jquery

If someone check-marks more than one checkbox (i.e. a sausage and pepperoni pizza), the total correct totals 5. However, if the user than undoes only ONE checkbox (like sausage), the total goes to 0. I need the total to only go to zero if ALL check boxes are unselected.

First attempt:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#pizzaOption>input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
      if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    var pizzaPrice=$(this).closest("#pizzaOption").data('price');
       $('#pizzaTotal').html("pizza: "+pizzaPrice);
    } else {
      var pizzaPrice=0;
      $('#pizzaTotal').html("pizza: " + pizzaPrice);
    }
    });
});
</script>
```

Second attempt. This attempt code does not work at all, but I would guess the solution may look something similar to this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#sodaOption>input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
      if ($('#sodaOption>input[type="checkbox"]').is(':checked')) {
    var sodaPrice=$(this).closest("#sodaOption").data('price');
       $('#sodaTotal').html("soda: "+ sodaPrice);
         var total +=sodaPrice;
      $('#total').html("total: "+ total);
    }   else ($(this).is(':unchecked')) { 
      var sodaPrice=0;
      $('#sodaTotal').html("soda: " + sodaPrice);
    }
    });
});
</script>
```

I expect the total to go to zero only if ALL checkboxes are not checked. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would simplify your approach. Since all your options have the same price, simply count how many inputs are checked in each group and multiply by price. The simplest way to do this is by adding a click handler to an element that wraps the checkboxes instead of the checkboxes themselves. Then query for the checked checkboxes and update accordingly.

```js
var $pizzaOptions = $( '.pizza-options' );
var pizzaPrice    = +$pizzaOptions.data( 'price' );
var $sodaOptions  = $( '.soda-options' );
var sodaPrice     = +$sodaOptions.data( 'price' );
var $pizzaTotal   = $( '.pizza-total' );
var $sodaTotal    = $( '.soda-total' );

function calculator( $totalEl, price, $options ) {
  return function ( e ) {
    $totalEl.text( price * $options.find( '[type="checkbox"]:checked' ).length );
  };
}

$sodaOptions.on( 'click', calculator( $sodaTotal, sodaPrice, $sodaOptions ) );
$pizzaOptions.on( 'click', calculator( $pizzaTotal, pizzaPrice, $pizzaOptions ) );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="order-form">

  <div class="pizza-options" data-price="5">
    <h2>Pizza</h2>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="sausage"> Sausage
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="pepperoni"> Pepperoni
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="mushrooms"> Mushrooms
    </label>
  </div>
  
  <div class="soda-options" data-price="2">
    <h2>Soda</h2>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="coke"> Coke
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="pepsi"> Pepsi
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="totals">
    <p>
      <strong>Pizza Total:</strong> <span class="pizza-total"></span>
    </p>
    <p>
      <strong>Soda Total:</strong> <span class="soda-total"></span>
    </p>
  </div>

</form>
```

Now, I may have gotten something wrong here as I do not know if the price is applied per option or if the price is the same regardless of 1 or more options being selected. If you require the latter, change:

`$totalEl.text( price * $options.find( '[type="checkbox"]:checked' ).length );`

to

`$totalEl.text( $options.find( '[type="checkbox"]:checked' ).length ? price : 0 );`

```js
var $pizzaOptions = $( '.pizza-options' );
var pizzaPrice    = +$pizzaOptions.data( 'price' );
var $sodaOptions  = $( '.soda-options' );
var sodaPrice     = +$sodaOptions.data( 'price' );
var $pizzaTotal   = $( '.pizza-total' );
var $sodaTotal    = $( '.soda-total' );

function calculator( $totalEl, price, $options ) {
  return function ( e ) {
    $totalEl.text( $options.find( '[type="checkbox"]:checked' ).length ? price : 0 );
  };
}

$sodaOptions.on( 'click', calculator( $sodaTotal, sodaPrice, $sodaOptions ) );
$pizzaOptions.on( 'click', calculator( $pizzaTotal, pizzaPrice, $pizzaOptions ) );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="order-form">

  <div class="pizza-options" data-price="5">
    <h2>Pizza</h2>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="sausage"> Sausage
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="pepperoni"> Pepperoni
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="mushrooms"> Mushrooms
    </label>
  </div>
  
  <div class="soda-options" data-price="2">
    <h2>Soda</h2>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="coke"> Coke
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="pepsi"> Pepsi
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="totals">
    <p>
      <strong>Pizza Total:</strong> <span class="pizza-total"></span>
    </p>
    <p>
      <strong>Soda Total:</strong> <span class="soda-total"></span>
    </p>
  </div>

</form>
```

**Note:** You also don't need multiple forms for each option, multiple `<script>` tags etc. Reuse code when you can. Create a function that is a template for repeated code that you can plugin that few parts that are different.

Comment: some may want 2 or 3 toppings, which is why i am struggling to think of a way for that. i could do a separate one for multiple toppings but this is a huge help. I probably need to do a select.length == 2 for that.

Comment: I'm not understanding your comment as far was what _"2 or 3 toppings"_ is going to affect. Are you talking about price? I did add a second example if option prices are a flat rate, i.e. as many toppings as you want is one price.

Comment: had time to tryout your sample codes. you're correct your second example worked too. might be easier to do .50 extra per topping on second thought. but i am just getting the foundations down first.